# How do I get a footer to stay at the bottom of the page when using Telerik controls?

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik, kendo-grid, sticky-footer

I have an asp.net MVC project using the most recent version of Telerik controls.  I have a shared view with a header at the top, menu on the left side, and a footer on the bottom.  In the middle is a section where I use a @RenderBody tag to show the main part of the page.  In that body are Telerik controls: grids, reports, drop down boxes, text boxes, etc.  On views with grids and reports, I'm unable to keep the footer at the bottom.  When there's a grid at the bottom of the view, the footer either is right under the grid (if it's small), not the bottom of the page; or the footer is pushed off the page (if the grid is large).  For reports, they go right over the top of the footer or they cover up the footer.  I've used this type of footer before without any problems, but I can't figure out how to get them to work with Telerik controls especially since they all interact with the footer differently.  I've looked at some of the other questions, but nothing seems to work for a page with Telerik grids and reports.

How do I get my footer to stay at the bottom of the page when using Telerik grids and reports?

Here is what I'd like to see:
[image]

Here are examples of what I am seeing:
Footer pushed off the screen by a Telerik grid.
[image]
Footer below the Telerik grid, but not on the bottom of the page.
[image]
Telerik report pushes footer off the page.
[image]
Telerik report is covering the footer.
[image]

Here is the code for the shared view:

```
@using App_Code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.common.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.mobile.all.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.dataviz.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/structure-main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/structure-main.css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jquery.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/scroller.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/jszip.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.all.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo/2015.3.1111/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/kendo.modernizr.custom.js")"></script>

<style>
    .menu ul li a {
        list-style: none !important;
        display: inline-block !important;
        height: 50px !important;
        vertical-align: middle !important;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100px !important;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding-top: 35px !important;
    }

    .menu ul li {
        text-align: center;
    }

    html {
        background-color: white;
    }

    .roundedButton {
        font-size: 1em !important;
        padding: 4px !important;
        margin-right: 4px !important;
        background-color: #d3dce0 !important;
        border: 1px solid #787878 !important;
        cursor: pointer !important;
        color: #333 !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    html {
        background-color: white;
    }

    footer {
        height: 40px !important;
        width: 100% !important;
        background-color: black !important;
        color: #555 !important;
        position: static !important;
        bottom: 0px !important;
    }

    .mainPage {
        overflow: hidden;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div>
            <img style="padding-left: 50px; width: 162px; height: 70px;" src="../Images/logo.png" />
            <div style="float: right;">
                Welcome @Html.Raw(Session["CurrUserName"])
                @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Login", null, new { @class = "roundedButton" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div style="float: none;">
    <div class="TransitionImage-Box transition-image-desktop skrollable skrollable-between" data-bottom-top="background-position: 50% -50%;" data-top-bottom="background-position: 50% 20%;" style="background-image: url(http://imavex.vo.llnwd.net/o18/clients/da-lubricant/images/Transition_Image/transition_image.jpg); background-attachment: fixed; background-position: 50% -19.3654%;"></div>
    <div class="TransitionImage-Box transition-image-tablet" style="background-image: url('http://imavex.vo.llnwd.net/o18/clients/da-lubricant/images/Transition_Image/transition_image.jpg');"></div>
</div>
<div class="mainPage">
    @RenderSection("styles", required: false)
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    <table style="margin: 0; margin-top: 0;">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div class="menu">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Menu()
                  .Name("Menu")
                  .Orientation(MenuOrientation.Vertical)
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100%;" })
                  .Items(items =>
                  {
                      items.Add().Text("Oil Analysis Reports").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "menuItem" }).Action("OAR_Selection", "Home");
                      items.Add().Text("Field Sample Reports").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "menuItem" }).Action("FieldSampleReports", "Home");
                      items.Add().Text("Fleet Reports").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "menuItem" }).Action("FleetReports", "Home");
                      items.Add().Text("Missed Units").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "menuItem" }).Action("MissedUnits", "Home");
                      items.Add().Text("Help").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "menuItem" }).Action("Help", "Home");
                  }))
                </div>
            </td>
            <td style="padding: 0px; float: left;">
                <section class="content-wrapper clear-fix">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        <footer>
            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <p>
                    &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year All rights reserved.  Performance Engineered Lubricants 
                </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
```

Here's the code for one of the views:

```
@using MyProject.App_Code
@model MyProject.Models.ModelCustomerDashboard


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Customer Dashboard";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_User.cshtml";
}

<style>
.cartTable td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0;
}

.cartTable thead {
    background-color: #1A78C2;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CustomerDashboard", "Home"))
{
    <div class="breadcrumb">
    @Html.Raw(@ClsUtility.GetCurrentCrumb("Customer Dashboard"))
    </div>
if (@ViewBag.Message != null && @ViewBag.Message != "")
{
    <div id="divErrorMessage" style="color: #1A78C2;">
        <br />
        @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.Message)
    </div>
    <br />
    <div style="clear: both">
        <br />
    </div>
}
<div style="text-align: center">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                Oil Analysis Dashboard
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Location:
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ddLocation)
                        .Name("ddLocation")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 500px;", onchange = "onChange_ddLocation(this)" })
                        .OptionLabel("Select from List")
                        .DataTextField("LocationName")
                        .DataValueField("LocationCode")
                        .BindTo(Model.locations)
                )
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="divMain" style="text-align:center;">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            Samples Processed:
                            @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.ddTimeframe)
                        .Name("ddTimeframe")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 250px;", onchange = "onChange_ddTimeframe(this)" })
                        .OptionLabel("Select a timeframe")
                        .DataTextField("text")
                        .DataValueField("value")
                        .BindTo(Model.timeframe)
                            )
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%">
                            <div class="chart-wrapper">
                                @(Html.Kendo().Chart<MyProject.Models.ModelSample>()
                                    .Name("chartSamplesProcessed")
                                    .Legend(legend => legend
                                        .Visible(true)
                                    )
                                    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("ReadSamplesProcessed", "Home", new { ddTimeframe = Model.ddTimeframe, ddLocation = Model.ddLocation, custNo = Model.custNo })))
                                    .Series(series => series.Pie(model => model.value, model => model.category, model => model.color)
                                    .Labels(labels => labels
                                        .Template("#= value#%")
                                        .Background("transparent")
                                        .Visible(true)
                                        )
                                    .StartAngle(0)
                                    )
                                    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                                        .Visible(true)
                                        )
                                    .ChartArea(x => x.Height(300))
                                )
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr style="text-align:left;">
                        <td>
                            Most Recent OARs
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.ModelSample>().Name("gridMostRecentOARs")
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                                .PageSize(2)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadMostRecentOARs", "Home", new { ddLocation = Model.ddLocation, custNo = Model.custNo }))
                            )
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(m => m.dateTaken).Title("Date Taken").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.unitNumber).Title("Unit Number");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.origLocationName).Title("Location");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.customerNotes).Title("Notes");
                            })
                        .Sortable()
                        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                            )
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:left">
                Samples Received, Now in Process
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyProject.Models.ModelSample>().Name("gridSamplesReceived")
                            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                .Ajax()
                                .Model(model => model.Id(m => m.analysisID))
                                .Batch(true)
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadSamplesReceived", "Home", new { ddLocation = Model.ddLocation, custNo = Model.custNo }))
                            )
                            .Columns(columns =>
                            {
                                columns.Bound(m => m.origLocationName).Title("Location");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.unitNumber).Title("Unit Number");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.compartmentName).Title("Compartment");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.dateTaken).Title("Date Taken").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.dateReceived).Title("Date Received").Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
                                columns.Bound(m => m.customerNotes).Title("Notes");
                            })
                        .Sortable()
                        .Pageable()
                        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                )
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.dropDownSource)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.custNo)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default in Telerik reports, page footer stays at bottom and the report footer does not. Still could not find a great answer for the question. I use conditions with page count to show content only in the last pages, page footer.